# excel breaks content in row to another row

Tags: excel

i have an excel sheet that i have exported from a website, i have noticed that in some particular rows the content jumps to a new line. i have searched online, but no credible answer to my problem
what is the cause of this and how can it be solved.
i have even tried to copy them one by one to make them be on the same line, but i cant keep on doin that
here is a link to my file.

[download](http://whitechapelandpartners.com/my_data%20(33).csv)

so that you can have a view of what i am talking about

Answer (score 0):

The address field in your file contains newlines in certain records. I suggest you open the file in Notepad and join these lines together before importing the file (make sure you turn word wrap off to see the lines correctly).